# how to split screen into two halves of 20/80 or 30/70 in HTML?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I have the following structure in HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <div class="leftside">
        ...leftside content here...
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col>
        <div class="rightside>
        ...rightside content here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this results into my page being split into 2 halves. I would like to have my leftside be 30% of the page, and the rightside 70%. How can I do this easily?

I'm working in the Django with Bootstrap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36801591/11475846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Bootstrap classes :)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="leftside">
    ...leftside content here...
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="rightside>
    ...rightside content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Use col-md for medium and above screens. You can use col-sm for small size screens.

You can refer from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with inlinestyle.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="display: "flex", flexFlow: "row", width: "20vw">
       <div class="leftside">
        ...leftside content here...
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col>
        <div class="rightside>
        ...rightside content here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap containers
100% = 12 md
using this ratio you can devide it as appx. 10 md and 2 md

other option is css flex:
you can use widht=80% and align_left and width=20% align_right